# Google Places API crash after installing app from play console

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-play-console, google-places-autocomplete

Before uploading my app to the play store I created a test version in play console.
The app has a places autocomplete field, However,when I installed the test version of my app from the playstore,every time I write in the autocomplete field something and then press spacebar its crash!

When testing the app on android studio it was working perfect without any errors or crashes.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:I am using this library of autocomplete ( https://github.com/seatgeek/android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView )

This is the crash report Title:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
```

Crash Report:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.json.GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.autocompleteFromStream (GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.java:14)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.model.Status.isSuccessful (Status.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.isErrorResponse (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.executeNetworkRequest (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient.executeAutocompleteRequest (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.PlacesApi.autocomplete (PlacesApi.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.adapter.PlacesApiFilter.performFiltering (PlacesApiFilter.java)
  at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage (Filter.java:236)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init> (TypeAdapters.java:87)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.create (TypeAdapters.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create (CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create (CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.json.GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.autocompleteFromStream (GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.java:14)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.model.Status.isSuccessful (Status.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.isErrorResponse (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.executeNetworkRequest (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient.executeAutocompleteRequest (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.PlacesApi.autocomplete (PlacesApi.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.adapter.PlacesApiFilter.performFiltering (PlacesApiFilter.java)
  at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage (Filter.java:236)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 
  at java.lang.Class.getField (Class.java:1604)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init> (TypeAdapters.java:34)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.create (TypeAdapters.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create (CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create (CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:68)
  or                     .setDelegate (Gson.java:68)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.json.GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.autocompleteFromStream (GsonPlacesApiJsonParser.java:14)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient$1.handleStreamResult (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.model.Status.isSuccessful (Status.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.isErrorResponse (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.executeNetworkRequest (HttpUrlConnectionMapsHttpClient.java:30)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.network.AbstractPlacesHttpClient.executeAutocompleteRequest (AbstractPlacesHttpClient.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.PlacesApi.autocomplete (PlacesApi.java)
  at com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.adapter.PlacesApiFilter.performFiltering (PlacesApiFilter.java)
  at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage (Filter.java:236)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: attach the crash report to your question

Comment: Crash report added,thanks Abdullah

Comment: okay, next, add the code where you parse the data, I believe there may be some problems with the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

So it was the proguard,I had to include the library in "proguard-rules.pro" like the following:

```
-keep class com.seatgeek.*{ *; }
-keep class com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete**{ *; }
-keep class com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.json**{ *; }
-keepclassmembers enum com.seatgeek.* { *; }
```